# Building avahi for use in the Oracle jvm (error: jni.h not found)

Tags: c++, ant, java, avahi

This is a follow up to the following question: [Compile errors when defining a macro to convert a case class instance into a map and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943462/compile-errors-when-defining-a-macro-to-convert-a-case-class-instance-into-a-map)

The answer there resolved my initial problem -- I was not installing the dependencies. However, now I have a problem because `ant clean all` is still not able to find `jni.h`. This is possibly because the instructions say to install open jdk 6. Is there a workaround for Oracle jdk 7. Here is the error that I'm getting:

```
myUser@ubuntu:~/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1$ ant clean all
Buildfile: /home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/build.xml

clean:
     [exec] make: Entering directory `/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/src'
     [exec] rm -f avahi4j_Client.o avahi4j_EntryGroup.o avahi4j_Avahi4JConstants.o thread-watch.o avahi4j_ServiceBrowser.o avahi4j_ServiceResolver.o avahi4j_RecordBrowser.o libavahi4j.so ./*~
     [exec] make: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/src'
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/classes

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/classes

jnilib:
     [exec] make: Entering directory `/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/src'
     [exec] gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/linux/ -I/usr/include/avahi-common  -O3 -fPIC -DVER_MAJ="0" -DVER_MIN="1"   -c -o avahi4j_Client.o avahi4j_Client.c
     [exec] make: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/src'
     [exec] avahi4j_Client.c:23:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
     [exec]  #include <jni.h>
     [exec]                  ^
     [exec] compilation terminated.
     [exec] make: *** [avahi4j_Client.o] Error 1

BUILD FAILED
/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/build.xml:75: exec returned: 2 

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my case, I needed to make the following change to `src/Makefile`:

```
# It must be a JDK, not a JRE !!! 
#JDK_HOME := /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun 
JDK_HOME := /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle 
#JDK_HOME := /usr/lib/j2sdk1.6-sun
```