# Compile errors when attempting to use macros defined in parent eclipse project ("has 2 unimplemented members")

Tags: eclipse, scala, macros

This is a follow up to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946187/type-mismatch-in-scala-quasiquote-of-macro-definition-type-mismatch-found-f/23948259#23948259) regarding getting generic `toMap` and `fromMap` (let's ignore fromMap for succinctness in the code snippet below) functionality working using Scala macros. Per the instructions, I created two projects: one that contains the macro definition that contains the below:

```
package mypackage

import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

trait Mappable[T] {
  def toMap(t: T): Map[String, Any]
}

object Mappable {
  implicit def materializeMappable[T]: Mappable[T] = macro materializeMappableImpl[T]

  def materializeMappableImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Mappable[T]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]
    val companion = tpe.typeSymbol.companionSymbol

    val fields = tpe.declarations.collectFirst {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isPrimaryConstructor => m
    }.get.paramss.head

    val toMapParams = fields.map { field =>
      val name = field.name.toTermName
      val decoded = name.decoded
      q"$decoded -> t.$name"
    }

    c.Expr[Mappable[T]] {
      q"""
      new Mappable[$tpe] {
        def toMap(t: $tpe): Map[String, Any] = Map(..$toMapParams)
      }
    """
    }
  }
}
```

The child project has the following file, which attempts to use the parent project's definition:

```
package mypackage2

import mypackage.Mappable

object MappableTest {

  case class Foo(name: String, id: Int) extends Mappable[Foo]

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val f = Foo("asdf", 3)
    println(f.toMap(f))
  }
}
```

However, this results in the following compile error, showing that the child project knows about Mappable, but not it's two members (side note: I'm not sure `f.toMap(f)` is the intended usage api -- is there a better way?):

```
class Foo needs to be abstract, since: it has 2 unimplemented members. /** As seen from class Foo, 
 the missing signatures are as follows. * For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations. 
 */ def fromMap(map: Map[String,Any]): mypackage2.MappableTest.Foo = ??? def toMap(t: 
 mypackage2.MappableTest.Foo): Map[String,Any] = ???
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and what I can do to make this work? I thought macros would work as long as the definition and usage were in separate projects, according to this [link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error is not about macros. It's about class Foo not implementing abstract mrmbers inheriting from Mappable.

Comment: Then am I misunderstanding how to use the Mappable trait? Is the case class not supposed to derive from Mappable? Can you suggest a simple example use of the Mappable trait?

Comment: I think I'm confused about the difference between the `Mappable` trait and the `Mappable` object, the use of the `implicit` definition, and the implications this has for how the client code is supposed to make use of this macro.

Comment: See the code example after "Any implementation of the Mappable[T] trait can now be used to convert a type T to and from a map. For example, we can define one manually".

Comment: Yes, I understand how to define one manually, but not this implicit one that is built with macros. I don't see any example of how to do it in the blog post. The only examples have manually built serializers and deserializers.